# How to copy folder items on disk mount automator

Tags: macos, finder, software-recommendation, automation

i want to automatically copy a specific folder's items when a usb is inserted at any given time. Program logic:

1. Once usb is available
2. simply copy all content of (/Users/x/Documents/myfolder) to usb folder such as (/Volumes/BOSS/myfolder)
3. deletes copied contents from myfolder

What software or scripts could do this?

Comment: Could you edit your body to list criteria? You tagged this with some options like automator, but it's not clear if you need a specific tool or would be happy with any solution.

Comment: sorry for that, any solution would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use Automator:

1. create a Folder Action on /Volumes
2. trigger an Applescript or shell script when a new drive is mounted
3. do the copy
4. grab a coffee (optional).

You'll probably want to scrape the output of `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` to make sure you're not messing around with DMGs.

Oooh, [option 2 from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1516034/55200) (copy/paste as a block quote below):

> You can use [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) for that purpose. Launchd can be configured
>   to automatically launch a program when a file path is modified.
>
> For example the following launchd config plist will launch the program
>   `/usr/bin/logger` when the desktop folder of my user account is
>   modified:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>     <key>Label</key>
>     <string>logger</string>
>     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
>     <array>
>         <string>/usr/bin/logger</string>
>         <string>path modified</string>
>     </array>
>     <key>WatchPaths</key>
>     <array>
>         <string>/Users/sakra/Desktop/</string>
>     </array>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```
>
> To activate the config plist save it to the LaunchAgents folder in
>   your Library folder as "logger.plist".
>
> From the shell you can then use the command `launchctl` to activate
>   the logger.plist by running:
>
> ```
> $ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/logger.plist
> ```
>
> The desktop folder is now being monitored. Every time it is changed
>   you should see an output in the system.log (use Console.app).  To
>   deactivate the logger.plist, run:
>
> ```
> $ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/logger.plist
> ```
>
> The configuration file above uses the `WatchPaths` option.
>   Alternatively you can also use the  `QueueDirectories` option. See the
>   [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) man page for more information.

Comment: I still have a problem, what is coding for the script specifically using the same code logic thanks. Im not a tech wizard so the more detail the better thanks.